# Indexing dynamic fields in azure search

Tags: azure, solr, azure-cognitive-search

I have used solr search engine which has a feature of dynamic fields. For example , if we define product_* field in the schema.xml, it will accept all the fields starting with product_ during the indexing.

Is there a feature like this in azure search where we can just define a wildcard for a field and it can accept the related fields in the indexing? As the fixed field thing reduces flexibility and one has to define a new schema every time for adding new fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Cognitive Search does not support dynamic fields. Adding fields to the schema as you detect them during indexing is the suggested workaround.

Please consider creating an item on our [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) page for this. While we haven't considered adding support for dynamic fields specifically, we have been looking at making schemas more flexible and extensible, and your input could help us prioritize this.